# Scilab Plot with 2D Area and Curve

Tags: plot, transition, scilab

how to create a Scilab plot with a filled (transparent?) color transition area between two limits. In this case the area should start at the read limit line going to the green limit with color transition from red to green. The blue function line should be part of the plot.
I tried to use `SFgrayplot` but could not manage it.
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a piece of code to do what you want. Do the background plot *before* other plots so that the colors will be added to the shaded color map. Adjust the [0,1] limits and it will be fine for your use case:

```
x=[0 1];
y=[0.2 0.8];
clf;
ncol=128;
gcf().color_map = linspace([1 0.6 0.6]',[0.6 1 0.6]',ncol)';
Sgrayplot(x,y,[0 1;0 1])

plot(0:1,0:1)

xgrid
gca().grid_position = "foreground"
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Stéphane again, that is what I was looking for. Let me check that out...

Comment: Based on your example I can now understand the help description of Scilab `colormap`. Thanks!